# Quotients in cyclotomic fields: $\mathbb{Z} [\zeta_{pqr}] /(1 - \zeta_p,1 - \zeta_q) \cong \mathbb{Z} [\zeta_{r}] /(pq) $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\zeta_{l}$ be a primitive $l$th root of unity for some integer $l$, $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_l)$  the $l$th cyclotomic field with $\mathcal{O}_{K} = \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_l]$ its ring of integers, and $\Phi_l (x)$ be the $l$th cyclotomic polynomial.

Let $n$ be an integer with several prime divisors, say $n = pqr$ where $p,q,r$ are distinct primes.

We have that

$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z} [\zeta_n]}{(1 - \zeta_p)} = \frac{\mathbb{Z} [\zeta_{qr},\zeta_p]}{(1 - \zeta_p)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z} [\zeta_{qr}] [X]}{(1 - X,\Phi_p(X))} = \frac{\mathbb{Z} [\zeta_{qr}] [1]}{(\Phi_p(1))} = \frac{\mathbb{Z} [\zeta_{qr}]}{(p)}
$$

where in the last step we have used the fact that $\Phi_l (1) = l$ whenever $l$ is prime.

Similarly, we have that

$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z} [\zeta_{qr}]}{(1 - \zeta_q)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z} [\zeta_{r}]}{(q)}
$$

Now, I'd be tempted (want) to apply a similar argument to say something like

$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z} [\zeta_{n}]}{(1 - \zeta_p,1 - \zeta_q)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z} [\zeta_{qr}]}{(p,1 - \zeta_q)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z} [\zeta_{r}]}{(pq)}
$$

Is this true? Is there a better way to prove/disprove it?

I'm concerned because I know that $\Phi_q (X)$ is not necessarily the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_q$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, only when $p$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_q^*$. (And if that is the case, do we know anything about $ m_q (1)$ where $m_q(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_q$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$?)

Any help or pointers to good references is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that as ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$ we have $(1-\zeta_p,1-\zeta_q)=(1-\zeta_{pq})$. Obviously the ideal on the left is contained in the ideal on the right simply because $(1-\zeta)\mid (1-\zeta^m)$ irrespective of the order of $\zeta$. By Bezout we have integers $u,v$ such that $uq-vp=1$. Here $1-\zeta_{p}^u=1-\zeta_{pq}^{uq}$ and $1-\zeta_q^v=1-\zeta_{pq}^{pv}$ are in the ideal on the left, and their difference is a unit times $1-\zeta_{pq}$. But, I don't know if this helps your cause :-(

Comment: Correct, usually $\Phi_q(X)$ does not remain irreducible modulo $p$, only when you say it does. But I'm not sure what problems that causes to you?

Comment: Thanks @Jyrki. Assuming you are correct on your first point, isn't it the case then that $ (1 - \zeta_{pq})$ is a unit, since it is a factor of $\Phi_{pq} (1) =1$. In which case the ideal and quotient are trivial?

Comment: Indeed, why didn't I think about it. That probably already follows from the fact that $(1-\zeta_p)$ and $(1-\zeta_q)$ lie above distinct rational primes.